# Can I get a pre-made android app opening a page in the default browser?

Tags: android

I tried to make an app for Android in the Android Studio, since I know Java, but the project got aborted in the middle because of technical issues (problems with the studio). So I thought, why not to remake the app in HTML, JS and CSS, which I know much better, put it on my site, and then just have an app that **opens** the "app" in the default browser?

So, could I get a **pre-made** android app (`.apk`) that just opens an url in the browser, let's say this one:

> http://rudyhoivt.neocities.org/android.html

because I don't have any way of developing with a studio.

Comment: You **could**. But this is not Android programming. This is just a web app running in a WebView.

Comment: I don't know if (but I have legit doubts that) Google will let you publish such an "app".

Comment: @LonnieZamora I agree, it's not Android programming after the crash - just a bit of Android :D

Comment: @BobMalooga I don't wanna publish it (yet (or maybe never))

Comment: ... not even a bit, in my opinion: it's just a shortcut to a webpage. Same as saving the URL as a desktop link.

Comment: @LonnieZamora Yes.

Comment: You can do that without even programming a single line of code. All from your browser. Save the shortcut and then send a copy of the shortcut to the home page.

Comment: @LonnieZamora I have a site (not listed in my profile) where I have freely downloadable apps **for Android**. It's better to have a "desktop shortcut" then nothing :)

Comment: `I don't have any half-done app (it got lost with the Android Studio)... I need to make the app without the studio ); ` A shortcut won't involve using Android Studio. Nor any other IDE.

Comment: @LonnieZamora so it's enough to make a single txt file and then convert it to a java format?

Comment: You don't even have do do that. Your (Android) browser does it. Just save the bookmark and then go to bookmarks, hold the link and choose Add to Home. DONE.

Comment: @LonnieZamora Great :D Now, where is this stored on the phone?

Comment: ... on your home page. Mind to do a bit of searching yourself? This is technically called "The Help-Vampire".

Comment: @LonnieZamora I meant where like in wich folders...

Comment: Read the above comment. please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `Intent` inside the `MainActivity` to open the webpage and then call `finish()` to kill the `MainActivity`

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://rudyhoivt.neocities.org/android.html"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
finish();
```

However, if you're going to create a webapp anyway, then consider checking [Cordova (PhoneGap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova) if you haven't done that before. You can use it to create apps using HTML, CSS, Javascript

Comment: Excellent! Could you just give me a done app? Thanks :D

Comment: I don't know what do you mean. It's just a few lines, add them in the MainActivity

Comment: I don't have any half-done app (it got lost with the Android Studio)... I need to make the app without the studio );